# Spring 3 beans cannot be initialized in jboss 7 which uses ResourceBundleMessageSource

Tags: spring, jboss7.x

I'm using `spring 3.0.5` and trying to migrate my application from `jboss 5.1 to 7.1.`

I'm having trouble initializing the beans which references messagesource.

I'm getting the following deployment **error**.

> ERROR
>   [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/riks-restaurant]]
>   (MSC service thread 1-12) Exception sending context initialized event
>   to listener instance of class
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'mybean' defined in ServletContext resource
>   [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type
>   'org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource' to
>   required type
>   'org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource' for
>   property 'resourceBundleMessageSource'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] to
>   required type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] for
>   property 'resourceBundleMessageSource': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:526)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
>   [spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
>   [spring-context-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>   [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>   [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>   [spring-web-3.0.5.RELEASE.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3392)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90)
>   [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]    at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811)
>     at
>   org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
>   [rt.jar:1.7.0_21] Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type
>   'org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource' to
>   required type
>   'org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource' for
>   property 'resourceBundleMessageSource'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] to
>   required type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] for
>   property 'resourceBundleMessageSource': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:481)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:518)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertForProperty(BeanWrapperImpl.java:512)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.convertForProperty(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1373)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1332)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    ... 19 more Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] to
>   required type
>   [org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource] for
>   property 'resourceBundleMessageSource': no matching editors or
>   conversion strategy found     at
>   org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterDelegate.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterDelegate.java:236)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    at
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.convertIfNecessary(BeanWrapperImpl.java:466)
>   [spring-beans-3.0.7.RELEASE.jar:3.0.7.RELEASE]    ... 25 more

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you compiled your code with different version of spring than what's loaded on your JBoss container. If you set some dependency to provided, double check they're all the same spring version

Comment: i havent used any spring library in provided scope.